# PhantomJS submit button not clicked - works in Selenium

Tags: phantomjs

I am having difficult with the submit button, it is not clicked in phantomJS the same code when run in Selenium works.
Does anybody have any suggestions (in Java) ?

public class BookFlight

{
       WebDriver driver;
       File file = new File("C:/Program Files/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
       @Test
       public void homePageFlightDetails() throws Exception
      {
           //Setup GhostDriver
           System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());

```
       //***************************************************
       // FIREFOX UI DEBUG - Set debug to True for UI debug
       boolean debug=false;
       if (debug)
          {
          driver= new  FirefoxDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          }
       else
       {
          driver=new PhantomJSDriver();
        //Set logging to Severe            Logger.getLogger(PhantomJSDriverService.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
       }

       //***************************************************
        //Submit Home page and get the title
        driver.get("http://www.aa.com");
        String pageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("The Current page title is  "+pageTitle); 

       //Find the origin airport field
       WebElement originAirport=driver.findElement(By.id("reservationFlightSearchForm.originAirport" ));
       //Clear any existing text and enter the origin airport
       originAirport.clear();
       originAirport.sendKeys("PHX");

       //Find the destination airport field
       WebElement destAirport=driver.findElement(By.id("reservationFlightSearchForm.destinationAirport" ));

       destAirport.clear();
       destAirport.sendKeys("LAS");

       //Find the depart date field
       WebElement depDate = driver.findElement(By.id("aa-leavingOn"));
       depDate.clear();
       depDate.sendKeys("08/20/2016");

       //Find the return date field
       WebElement retDate = driver.findElement(By.id("aa-returningFrom"));
       retDate.clear();
       retDate.sendKeys("08/24/2016");

       //Find the Search up button
       // WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("flightSearchForm.button.reSubmit"));
       // driver.findElement(By.id("flightSearchForm.button.reSubmit")).click();
      // WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Search'][@type='submit']"));

       //phantomjs debug  - Verify the button has been found
       boolean buttonText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Search'][@type='submit']")).isDisplayed();
       System.out.println("buttonText Boolean is = "+buttonText);

       //Click the Search button         
       //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Search'][@type='submit']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

              //***********  This works in Selenium *********** 
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='Search'][@type='submit']")).click();
       // Wait for the Choose Flights page to appear
       int count = 1;
       do
          if (driver.getTitle().contains("Choose flights"))
          {
                 break;
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("do loop iteration "+count+ " the title = "+ driver.getTitle());
             Thread.sleep(1000);
                    count++;
          }
       while (count < 30);            
       System.out.println("After search the current page title is  = "+ driver.getTitle());
       Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains("Choose flights"));
       driver.quit();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering a similar issue when using phantomjs via Jmeter (with [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=WebDriverSampler)).

What I can see is that a modal exists on the page which is overlaying the fields I need to interact with.  I can add assertions to verify the fields and buttons exists and capture their values, just cant click on the button.

The only workaround that I can think of is calling the function (button onclick function) although not my preference.